# replace the content of one field based on the content in another field

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to divide the first column based on the delimiter, here `-`. Based on the last value, last column, here column 2, should be populated. If the value is `01` or `99` then replace with `2` or `1` respectively.

```
#input
PE01-02-01  -9
PE01-02-99  -9
PE01-03-01  -9
PE01-03-99  -9
PE01-05-01  -9
PE01-05-99  -9

#output
PE01-02-01  2
PE01-02-99  1
PE01-03-01  2
PE01-03-99  1
PE01-05-01  2
PE01-05-99  1
```

could you please provide a suggestion on how to achieve this ? I was trying to break down the first column into array, access the last element and then update the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this somewhat cryptically using nested [conditional operators ?:](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_117.html) (aka ternary operators)

```
awk '{$2 = $1 ~ /-01$/? 2: $1 ~ /-99$/? 1: $1; print}' input

PE01-02-01 2
PE01-02-99 1
PE01-03-01 2
PE01-03-99 1
PE01-05-01 2
PE01-05-99 1
```

Alternately

```
awk '{n = split($1, a, "-"); $2 = a[n] == "01" ? 2: a[n] == "99"? 1: a[n]; print}' input
```

Comment: I was trying to break down the first column into array, access the last element and then update the second column. But, your approach is good, can you please explain on how it achieve the task ?

Comment: @Prradep, `$1 ~ /-01$/` and `$1 ~ /-99$/` are regular expression-based conditionals that check to see if the first field ends with `-01` and `-99` respectively. I've provided an alternate form that splits field 1 into an array and performs checks against the last member of the array - see if that's easier to follow

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ane 'BEGIN { $" = "\t" }
           $F[0] =~ /(..)$/,
               $F[-1] = { "01" => 2, "99" => 1 }->{$1} || $F[-1];
           print "@F\n" ' input_file > output_file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array.
- `$"` is set to tab so that the array members are tab separated in double quotes (`"@F"`)
- `$F[0]` is matched against a regex which extracts its last two characters into `$1`
- `$F[-1]`, the last column, is set to 2 or 1 based on `$1`. If `$1` is something else, the original value is kept.